# Why to use function to get an objects property when you can access it directly?

Tags: c#, .net-core

For example, you have [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.isemailconfirmedasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0) function in
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`:

```
public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> IsEmailConfirmedAsync (TUser user);
```

which according to the documentation returns a flag indicating whether the email address for the specified user has been verified. But, assuming that you use the default `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` user type `IdentityUser`, you can just access the property directly like this:

```
user.EmailConfirmed
```

So my questions are:

1. What is the purpose of such function?
2. Isn't accessing the property directly faster?
3. In general, why would you use one over the other?

Edit: Well, I have just looked at the implementation of the function and it looks like it does something more than just return the property, unfortunately I don't really understand it. Perhaps someone can help?

Comment: I [don't see a UserManager.EmailConfirmed property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn613245(v=vs.108)).

Comment: `which just returns one of the properties of the object you pass to it` How confident are you that that is _all_ it does?

Comment: `For example, you have this function:` Where did you find this function?

Comment: @mjwills I found it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.isemailconfirmedasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @mjwills And admittedly not a lot. I've just looked at the implementation and it does something with an email store, I'll investigate that!

Comment: @RaymondChen It says TUser user, not UserManager. TUser can be IdentityUser class for example, which has the property.

Comment: @sladekm I don't think you realize who you just spoke to...

Comment: @Dai I am not sure what do you mean by that. I didn't want to sound disrecpectful or anything, I just didn't understand.

Comment: @sladekm Raymond Chen is _kinda a big deal_...

Comment: The function IsEmailConfirmedAsync is a method that declared by UserManager&lt;TUser&gt;, that means TUser is a generic type parameter, and the TUser doesen't needs to implement a property of 'EmailConfirmed'. so you may treat any class type as user type, no matter whether it is a class derieved from IdentityUser.

In another way, if you use IdentityUser, you have to ensure your user model mathes the IdentityUser.

Comment: Okay, now I understand the question after it has been edited to clarify. There is no requirement that the `TUser` have an EmailConfirmed` property. If it has one, then great! But it might not. The information is abstracted into a method so that each provider can choose how to respond.

Comment: @RaymondChen (and dexiang) Thank you, I now understand. I really misuderstood the point of the method and worded my question wrong. I'll do a better job next time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the function even exist?

Because *ASP.NET Identity* is database-agnostic. If you want to use an existing user account database, or a non-database solution (e.g. LDAP, Active Directory, some obscure IBM COBOL-based system from decades ago, etc) with ASP.NET Identity [then you need to reimplement `UserStore` and other types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

> Is it because of readibility?

No, as I said: it's because ASP.NET Identity cannot magically know the status of your user's e-mail confirmation status without you telling it *how* to do that by implementing `IsEmailConfirmedAsync`.

> Isn't accessing the property directly faster?

I assume by "the property" you mean [the `IdentityUser.EmailConfirmed` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityuser-1.emailconfirmed?view=aspnetcore-5.0). The answer is "no" because you don't have to use `IdentityUser` with ASP.NET Identity. You can use **any** class to represent your users (that's why it's a generic class with `TUser` as a generic type parameter), and that's also why you need to implement `IsEmailConfirmedAsync`.

Also, because the `IdentityUser.EmailConfirmed` property is *cached* after it's loaded: accessing the property will retrieve the cached/pre-loaded value of `EmailConfirmed` rather than forcing a refresh/manual-check. And *even if* the property-getter did do a forced refresh on every getter-invocation that would be a terrible software design because accessing a database involves IO, and IO means *blocking the thread* as well as allowing all kinds of error conditions to creep-in - this breaks the design principles of C#/.NET property-getters which should be side-effect free (as well as being necessarily synchronous, which automatically makes them inappropriate for anything involving IO, especially as ASP.NET Core 3+ will throw an exception at you (by default) unless you use async IO methods.

> In general, why would you use one over the other?

You wouldn't - one is the *model representation* of the user's state (`IdentityUser`) and the other is the *implementation* of the logic that *figures out what the user's state is* from the database or external authX system (`UserStore`).

It's just that if you are using Entity Framework Core, then you can just use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`'s implementation which doesn't require you to reimplement all of the above.